# Sublime Text 3 c++ 'this' keyword syntax highlight

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

When viewing C++ code in sublime text 3, my 'this' keyword is not colored as a keyword, instead it is just plain white.

I am not sure if this is the standard syntax coloring out of the box for sublime text 3, or I have somewhere down the road broken something in my configuration.

How can I change my syntax highlighting for C++ to color the 'this' keyword, in the same way that 'true' or 'false' would be colored?

Comment: @TankorSmash this is a poor fit there, see [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with (you even got the site name wrong)

Comment: This should work out of the box. Make sure the syntax is set properly (bottom right of status bar should say C++) and that you're not overriding it with a non-standard one. You might also try a different color scheme in case the colors in the one you're using are messed up. To answer your question more specifically, in order to change the syntax highlighting of `this` you would need to modify the syntax file to give it a different scope.

Comment: @gnat it was like a month ago, give a guy some slack http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/its-official-programmers-is-now-software-engineering-stack-exchange

Comment: How do I know if I am overriding with a non-standard one?

Comment: Turns out it was my color scheme that was just inadequate.

Comment: @TankorSmash faq guidance referred in my prior comment was posted very long time ago. That you _additionally_ missed site name is kind of an icing on a cake

Comment: The Sublime devs have done a lot of work lately on updating the syntax definitions and standardizing the scopes they use, so older color schemes need to be updated to take advantage.